# Can JaggedArray counts innermost layer and return another JaggeredArray?

Tags: uproot, awkward-array

```py
so_jaggered = awkward.fromiter([[[0, 1, 2]], [[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]])
so_jaggered.counts
```

Current version 0.12.13 returns

```
array([1, 2, 2])
```

However, I want to count only the innermost part, which can be achieved by following code:

```
count_so_jaggered = np.array([[len(x) for x in trks] for trks in so_jaggered])
```

and output looks:

```
array([list([3]), list([2, 2]), list([3, 2])], dtype=object)
```

But it has at least two drawbacks: slow and dtype=object. Any plans to support such feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```py
awkward.JaggedArray(so_jaggered.starts, so_jaggered.stops,
                    so_jaggered.content.counts)
```

which returns

```
<JaggedArray [[3] [2 2] [3 2]] at 0x797274f58630>
```

Also, there's a reducer method (like `sum`, `min`, `max`) that does this directly:

```py
so_jaggered.count()
```

which returns

```
<JaggedArray [[3] [2 2] [3 2]] at 0x7b7fd8f53f60>
```

Notice that the property (returning outermost number of entries) is called `counts` with an "s" and requires no parentheses, while the reducer method (returning innermost number of entries) is called `count` without an "s" and requires parentheses. This was a design mistake and [Awkward 1.0](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0#readme) will replace both with a single reducer that has an `axis` parameter (`axis=0` returns the outermost level, `axis=-1` returns the innermost, and other values are everywhere in between).

Also, reducers don't count missing values (`None`, from `MaskedArrays`, or `NaN` in floating-point), if you have any of those, which is another way that `count` differs from `counts`. This, too, should become an optional parameter to give the user more control. You found a weak point in the awkward-array interface.

Comment: (If you read this earlier, I expanded on the answer because I didn't remember `.count()` at first.)